# Graph API - how to get data from facebook 'unofficial' pages

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am using python sdk to get data from specific facebook pages. This works fine when the page is an official page and I request the feed.

```
access_token = facebook.get_app_access_token(APP_ID, APP_SECRET)
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
page = graph.get_object(PAGE_OFFICIAL)
posts = graph.get_connections(PAGE_OFFICIAL, "feed")
print posts
```

However, some of the pages that I am working with are deemed 'unofficial pages'. E.g. https://www.facebook.com/pages/Whittington-Hospital/112221552128426?fref=ts

They are place pages in which data is aggregated that mentions the place - i.e. if someone checks into the location and the pages also features reviews and ratings. From what I can tell the reviews are not possible to get through the graph API thus far (although I found a post a few years ago saying that this functionality was being added in soon...).

For these unofficial pages I get an empty dict back:

```
{u'data': []}
```

As it's an unofficial page there are no administrators for these pages that I could contact for an access key. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unofficial pages do not have a feed, but like you mentioned, reviews and mentions only. Currently there is no way to access reviews or page mentions via the API. Also, because no one has claimed that page yet there is no admin and no page token you could acquire.

So the final answer would be: No, you cannot access the reviews or mentions via the API for unofficial pages.

Comment: Thanks, very much. That's what I feared.